# PHP simplexml_load_file - ignore xml object if it's empty

Tags: php, xml

I am using simplexml_load_file to gather information from an xml and put it in relevant places in a txt file.

I want to ignore certain parts if they are empty. For example if I have address line 1 to 5, and address line 5 is empty then I want it to be ignored.

Here is what I have tried to ignore empty objects:

```
if($xml->ContactAddress->Address5 != '') {
    fwrite($txt, $xml->ContactAddress->Address5 . "\r\n");
}

if($xml->ContactAddress->Address5) {
    fwrite($txt, $xml->ContactAddress->Address5 . "\r\n");
}
```

With both of these a blank line is still being inputted, so what is the correct way to check if t is blank or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isset()`:

```
if(isset($xml->ContactAddress->Address5)) {
    fwrite($txt, $xml->ContactAddress->Address5 . "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: That gives me an error: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: Is that because you havent got the address5 tag in the first part though. For me I will always have <address5></address5> Just sometimes empty, sometimes not

Comment: Sorry if empty it is actually: <Address5/>

Comment: Sorry for that, misread the _address line 5 is empty_. Will update my answer momentarily.

Comment: Comparing with empty string works as well - see [https://3v4l.org/4X94d](https://3v4l.org/4X94d)

Comment: Yep it is working for me, I must have typoed something when trying it first. Thanks